# Importing vector ".shp" file in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo, qgis

I digitized the roads of an area from Google Earth, Saved them to .Kml format, Then I opened this kml data file in QGIS 2.1 and converted it into ESRI shape file in WGS84 CRS. The file is successfully converted to shape file. But when I imported this file in NetLogo, a run-time error occurred which is

"Extension exception: unsupported shape type 13 error while observer running GIS:LOAD-DATASET"

My code is

```
gis:load-coordinate-system (word "Roads.prj")

to setup
    let paths-dataset gis:load-dataset "Roads.shp" // error line
    gis:set-world-envelope  gis:envelope-of paths-dataset
    foreach gis:feature-list-of paths-dataset
    [
       gis:set-drawing-color blue
       gis:draw ? 1.0
    ]
 end
```

Roads.shp is very small size 3kb only because I am learning how to import vector file in  NetLogo I digitized four roads only.

I want to know why this error is there. In one link I found that the "type 13 error" occurs when data is in 3D and the tool in which the .shp is being imported supports 2D.

Is this the reason? How do I will know the file which I converted using QGIS is in 2D or 3D. If it is in 3D how to convert it into 2D shape file (.shp)

Comment: I see a similar question ("unsupported shape type 13") on netlogo-users went unanswered: http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/error-in-reading-vectordataset-td5004309.html