# Netlogo GIS - Unsupported file type - shapefile

Tags: gis, netlogo, qgis

I have created a shapefile from a CSV file using the QGIS export layer feature. I then stripped out the z/m information using the vector processing tools, as per other posts on this topic (below).  However, Netlogo still says it is an unsupported file type.  Is there anything else I am missing?

other posts:

- [NetLogo GIS extension: Unsupported file type 21 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57999738/netlogo-gis-extension-unsupported-file-type-21-error)
- [netlogo, gis extension not drawing and giving an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55352775/netlogo-gis-extension-not-drawing-and-giving-an-error)
- [Importing vector ".shp" file in NetLogo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966966/importing-vector-shp-file-in-netlogo)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround, but not a great solution was to import to SAGA (packaged with QGIS) and export as a shapefile. Clearly the two programs treat shapefiles a little differently.